# Unknown objects on a time-lapse video of the starry sky

Tags: identify-this-object

This is a random timelapse video of the starry sky https://dzen.ru/video/watch/638872052b36453f40e45ada?t=3.
Throughout the film, many luminous objects are seen moving across the sky.
I have seen similar videos before several times, this phenomenon is not unique.
Most objects move along a horizontal path, but some maneuver, disappear, or move almost vertically.
I have not found a satisfactory explanation of what it could be.
The simplest explanation is airplanes.
But the trajectory of some objects excludes this version, planes do not fly like that. None of the objects leave a trail of condensation behind them.
It can't be satellites, as satellites can't fly in random directions or maneuver. According to visual assessment, the height of the flight of objects seems to be small, within the lower atmosphere.
Objects cannot be meteorites because meteorites cannot move parallel to the earth, from horizon to horizon.
What is it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just airplanes.  Maybe with some satellites mixed in.  They aren't moving "vertically", they are moving away from the camera, and perspective makes it vertical.

Comment: You should explain what "like that" is when you say "planes do no fly like that", and supply supporting evidence.

Answer (score 1):

Those are airplanes flying across the camera's field of view in various directions. I'm not sure what about the trajectory suggests to you that they can't possibly be planes. Some of them appear at the top of the frame and move "down" to the horizon line, which is what we would expect for an aircraft coming from almost directly behind the camera and continuing on past the horizon.

It's important to remember that people can't reliably identify the distance to a light in the dark without context clues (like objects of known size or location that the light is moving in front of or behind). Since the sky usually lacks such clues, it's nearly impossible to accurately judge the altitude and distance to a light. That means we also can't reliably identify *changes* in distance to a light in the sky. It's very common for observers to mistake lights moving towards or away as movement up or down (and even experienced observers can make that mistake).

If that answer still seems unsatisfactory, I would encourage you to imagine what you think a light on an airplane flying over the camera at high altitude would look like, and specify what elements of the video seem like they don't match that scenario.

(You mentioned contrails, and to that I would merely say you need the right conditions to get contrails. Most airplanes *don't* produce contrails most of the time.)

Comment: I agree that planes are the most likely explanation.
I took some good screenshots of the video, which show the trajectories of objects.
one of them clearly shows that one trace is double. (I have added a picture to the question.)
Can an airplane leave such a trail?

Comment: Sure it can. What sort of streak would it produce if it had a light on each wingtip?

Comment: (You can also have multiple aircraft following nearly parallel courses; the circled lines in the last screenshot are not parallel at all, that appears to just be two planes going roughly the same way.)